# Why does document.write and console.log give different outputs for getElementById?

Tags: javascript, html

```
var myListItems = document.getElementById ("li");
function myList () {console.log (myListItems)};
function myWrist () {document.write (myListItems)};
myList();
myWrist();
```

For the JavaScript above, why does document.write output - `[object HTMLLIElement]`, whereas console.log outputs `<li id="li">fdsf</li>`?

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console varies depending on browser. However, most consoles will output the object and its structure if one exists whereas when using document.write it calls `toString` and then writes the result of that to the page.

That is why you see the object representation in the console, versus the string representation on the page.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("li").toString());
```

```html
<li></li>
```